# store data in a class array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to learn swift on my own, but I have hit a small wall, what am I missing here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmZUu.png

```
import Foundation

class aluno
{
    var cpf: String?
    var notaP1: Double = 0.0
    var notaP2: Double = 0.0
    var notaFinalAluno: Double = 0.0
}

var condiçaoLoop = 1
var count = 0

func verificaNota()
{
    while condiçaoLoop != 0
    {
        print("Digite o cpf do aluno")
        let cpfAluno = readLine()
        print("Digite a nota da P1 do aluno")
        let notaP1Aluno = Double(readLine()!)
        print("Digite a nota da P2 do aluno")
        let notaP2Aluno = Double(readLine()!)

        let notaFinalAluno = (notaP1Aluno! + notaP2Aluno!)/2

        if notaFinalAluno >= 7
        {
            print("Aluno aprovado com média: \(notaFinalAluno)")
            print("Deseja verificar mais algum aluno? 1 Sim  0 Não")
            let resposta = Int(readLine()!)
            if resposta == 0
            {
                condiçaoLoop = 0
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("Aluno de final com média: \(notaFinalAluno)")
            print("Deseja verificar mais algum aluno? 1 Sim  0 Não")
            let resposta = Int(readLine()!)
            if resposta == 0
            {
                condiçaoLoop = 0
            }
        }
        count += 1
    }
    for i in 1...count
    {
        var notasAlunos: [aluno] = []
        notasAlunos.cpf[i] = cpfAluno
        notasAlunos.notaP1[i] = notaP1Aluno!
        notasAlunos.notaP2[i] = notaP2Aluno!
        notasAlunos.notaFinalAluno[i] = notaFinalAluno
    }
}
verificaNota()
```

what im trying to do is get two grades from the user, calculate its final score and then store the data in an array

Comment: What is going wrong? What do you see?

Comment: the image didnt load, sorry i see this when i try to compile it:
Nota.swift:52:24: error: use of unresolved identifier 'cpfAluno'
                notasAlunos.cpf[i] = cpfAluno
:53:27: error: use of unresolved identifier 'notaP1Aluno'
                notasAlunos.notaP1[i] = notaP1Aluno!
Calcular_Nota.swift:51:7: note: did you mean 'notasAlunos'?
                var notasAlunos: [aluno] = []
54:27: error: use of unresolved identifier 'notaP2Aluno'
                notasAlunos.notaP2[i] = notaP2Aluno!
note: did you mean 'notasAlunos'?
                var notasAlunos: [aluno] = []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the constants that you define inside your `while` loop have no scope outside the loop. They exist inside the loop but not outside it. Define `cpfAluno` etc, before (outside) the `while` loop so that they are available inside the `for in` loop.

```
    func verificaNota()
    {
       var cpfAluno = 0.0
       var notaP1Aluno = 0.0
       var notaP2Aluno = 0.0
       var notaFinalAluno = 0.0

       while condiçaoLoop != 0
       {
          print("Digite o cpf do aluno")
          cpfAluno = readLine()
          print("Digite a nota da P1 do aluno")
          notaP1Aluno = Double(readLine()!)
          print("Digite a nota da P2 do aluno")
          notaP2Aluno = Double(readLine()!)

          notaFinalAluno = (notaP1Aluno! + notaP2Aluno!)/2
```

Comment: That did the trick, thats something i notice with if statements, swift seens to isolate varibles inside loops or condition statements, very odd to me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in your for loop you are defining a new array instead of a new aluno object. Try this:

```
var notasAlunos: [aluno] = [] 
for i in 1...count
    {
        var novoAluno: Aluno()
        novoAluno.cpf[i] = cpfAluno
        novoAluno.notaP1[i] = notaP1Aluno!
        novoAluno.notaP2[i] = notaP2Aluno!
        novoAluno.notaFinalAluno[i] = notaFinalAluno
        notasAlunos.append(novoAluno)
    }
```

Comment: Mergin your solution with Magnas one solved my problem. Thank you